# How to read php socket connection response?

Tags: php, sockets, fread

Following is my socket connection request and response order.

```php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$connection = socket_connect($socket, $Host, $Port);
$Md5CheckSum = md5($msg); 
$WillWait = 'SOAP  '. $Md5CheckSum. '  WILL_WAIT'."\n";
socket_write($socket,$WillWait);                        
socket_write($socket,$msg);
socket_write($socket,  SoapSender::$TERM_CHAR);
sleep(1);
$buf = socket_read($socket, 2048);
//socket_write($socket,"&\r\n");
echo "$buf\n";
```

Please could somebody tell me how to read response that I receive after last socket_write request. I have been searching for this answer all day but have not been able to find any help through Google.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: What do you receive in `$buf`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make multiple socket_write and socket_recv calls in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028272/how-to-make-multiple-socket-write-and-socket-recv-calls-in-php)

Comment: @Celada The link You provided does not work...

Comment: @shadyyx the OP deleted the previous version of the question.

Comment: Can you please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two functions should be used:

```
stream_set_blocking($socket, true);
```

And

```
stream_get_contents($socket);
```

Setting a block on your stream requires the return of data before your application will continue execution of the script.

If you do not set a stream block, sometimes latency will cause your PHP script to think there was no response, causing you to not receive data.

Also, use stream_get_contents to pull from the socket. This will grab by default the full buffer.

Comment: I am getting Warning: stream_get_contents(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource if I use the stream_get_contents($socket) function. Thank for your help again!

Comment: I am new to the socket level programing and I realy do not know where insert one of your two options in my code. Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Please anyone there, please answer to the following question                                                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195381/multiple-read-writes-on-a-single-socket-connection-in-php

Answer (score -1):

The correct way is to use socket_read, not stream_get_contests as someone else suggested.

Here is an example:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

$result = socket_connect($sock, "10.197.24.40", "5000");

$request = '{ "request" : { "id" : "some_function_id",  "data": "55555555-5"} }';

// We send the request
socket_write($sock,$request);

socket_read($sock,1000000);

socket_close($sock);
```

I have tested this code in a live environment and it works correctly.